# Execute a function after collection update in angular meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm creating a multiplayer game, and I want a specific function to be executed after the first player updates a "isStarted" field in the collection.

Inside my controller, I have:

```
angular.module('mcitygame').directive('gcaseGame', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'client/gcases/gcase-game/gcase-game.html',
    controllerAs: 'gcaseGame',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams, $reactive, $window, $element) {

        $reactive(this).attach($scope);

        this.subscribe('gcases'); // This is the collection I need to watch if the "isStarted" field has changed

        this.helpers({
            gcase: () => {
                return GCases.findOne({_id: 'dynamicID'}) //I'm using  $stateParams.gcaseId, which I get from the router, but I put 'dynamicID' just for the purpose of this example.
            });

        this.startGame = function(option){
            if(option == 1) {
                console.log(" Users clicked me from the interface!");
                GCases.update({_id :'dynamicID'}, {
                    $set: {isStarted: true, updatedAt: Date.now()}
                });
            } else {
                console.log("I am here because someone called me from a different client!");
            }

        };

        ////////////////////////// I need to be able to do something like this
        this.autorun(() => { 
            if(this.gcase.isStarted){
                console.log(" isStartred = " + this.gcase.isStarted);
                this.startGame();
            }
        });
        ////////////////////////// or this
        this.gcase.observeChanges({
            changed: function (id, gcase) {
                console.log(" isStartred = " + this.gcase.isStarted);
                this.startGame();
            }
        });
        //////////////////////////

    }
}})
```

Outside the controller, I have:

```
GCases = new Mongo.Collection("gcases");
```

Any help would be really appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.. The way I've done it is like this:

```
    var that = this; // I did this since I need to call it from inside 'observeChanges'
    GCases.find({_id:'dynamicID'}).observeChanges({ //'this.gcase', as proposed in the question, was returning an error saying it's not a function
        changed: function (id, gcase) {
            console.log(" isStartred = " + gcase.isStarted);
            that.startGame(2); // any value beside 1 will invoke the 'else' condition, and the log will only appears on other clients consoles
        }
    });
```

and it worked. I'm not sure if there is a nicer way, but this is one way to go. Hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback function in update.

Comment: That's not going to help him if the update is made by a different client.